# How to setup Docker Registry 2.1 health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, docker-registry, health-monitoring

I tried to configure an AWS ELB to accept 401 as healthy, because the registry has basic authentication and I am ok with treating it as a healthy response. But the ELB does not support that. So instead what can I do if my registry requires basic authentication? Any other solutions for this other than setting up a proxy?

Comment: Are you sure, ELB can't do the health check properly? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-healthchecks.html

Comment: Yes I am sure, it only accepts "2xx" response as healthy, everything else is unhealthy. But in my case a 401 response is enough to signal that it is healthy.

Answer (score 0):

In the registry 2.0 there some api can be used to check the health. Such as /v2/. It was use for the docker command to check the docker registry version. We have config the v2 for health check.

Comment: That returns a 401 since I set up authentication for the registry, but ELB only takes 200 response to register as healthy